# sed remove select char and everything before first occurrence of character in line

Tags: regex, shell, sed

i find this regex
`sed -i 's/.*\(:.*\)/\1/g' file.txt` for remove before `:` but i need remove the `:` too, the result apllying this regex in:

```
[09/11/2020 15:01:37] Name: Hello!
```

return:

```
Hello!
```

but i need only

```
Hello!
```

Comment: Take the `:` out of the `()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -i 's/.*: *//' file.txt
```

This will remove all text up to last `:` including `:` and all spaces (if any) right after the `:`.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/NTQlGF):

```
#!/bin/bash
s='[09/11/2020 15:01:37] Name: Hello!'
sed 's/.*: *//' <<< "$s"
# => Hello!
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a capture group to copy everything after the `:`, replace everything up to the `:` with an empty string.

```
sed -i 's/^.*://' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, more simply with `cut` :

```
cut -d ':' -f 4
```

With `-d` you choose the delimiter which is the space

With `-f` you choose the right colon you need

result :

```
Hello!
```

bye

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).